# MasterCard / EMV Tags - Detail Definition

Tags: emv, mastercard

I'm working on a project that requires me to parse the EMV data tags that I receive from a MasterCard purchase transaction. I'm using the EMV V4.3 Books from EMVCo and have access to the MasterCard documentation via MasterCard Connect.

I need to find the official documentation that details the definition of each tag.

**For example**: Tag 9F10 (Issuer Application Data).

- Byte 1 represents the Key Derivation Index
- Byte 2 represents the Crypto Version Number
- Byte 3 to Byte 8 represents the Card Verification Results

The EMVCo books detail some of the tags but not all. Can anyone point me to the correct documentation to use?

Much appreciated

Regards,
Dev

Comment: I don't know such a docucument that explain every tag. But beside document you can reference these page. It parse the tag for you. https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/   and  https://tvr-decoder.appspot.com/t/decode/8E/EMV/0000000000000000410342031E031F02

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download **M/Chip Requirements—For Contact and Contactless • 29 September 2016** and then read section **Appendix B Analysis of DE 55**

This has list of mandatory and optional tags you will receive in a MasterCard online transaction and has detailed explanation of tags, its data, and sub elements. It also has explanation for each Bit wherever applicable. Enjoy!!

Comment: This is exactly the document that I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete list of all EMV tags her:
https://www.eftlab.com/knowledge-base/145-emv-nfc-tags/